# How can I allow someone who isn't my Facebook friend to like my photo?

Tags: facebook, photos, friends

I want people to like my album/photo since I'm joining a quiz. Unfortunately, even though I set my album as public, a non-friend can't like it.

How do I change the setting?

Answer (score 2):

Try going to http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=timeline - right to "Who can see things on my timeline?" there will be "Who can see posts you've been tagged in on your timeline?" and next to that an "Edit" button. Press it and change the setting to 'Everyone'.

Comment: Your method doesn't work... I changed all my setting to Everyone and Public. Still people who are not my friend cannot see the like button